# How to pass settings to rq task?

Tags: python

I wonder what's the best approach to pass settings from a RQ worker to task function?

I want to keep all of my settings outside of the app in text file, then read it while worker is starting and then have those values for performing the actual task.

Right now I'm using os.environ.

Thanks!

Comment: rq?  Is that http://python-rq.org/ ?

Comment: @Warren Weckesser seems to be.

Answer (score 1):

It appears from the [documentation](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/) from the section "Custom worker classes" that the way to do this is to write a custom worker class. Here is a pattern that I've been using which loads a section from a `ConfigParser` file into a virtual python module named `config`:

```py
import configparser
import rq.worker
import sys
import types


class ConfigurableWorker(rq.worker.Worker):
    """An RQ Worker class which loads configuration from config.ini"""

    def work(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Perform RQ work"""

        # Store some configuration on a virtual module
        sys.modules['config'] = types.ModuleType('config')
        import config
        config_reader = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config_reader.read('config.ini')
        for key, value in config_reader['rq'].items():
            setattr(config, key, value)

        # Do work
        super().work(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then from the job function:

```py
def my_bunch_of_work():
    import config
    con = db_connection(url=config.my_db_connection)
```

Running the rq worker with a customer worker class can be done with the `--worker-class` argument.

```
$ rq worker --worker-class my.prog.ConfigurableWorker
```

It might be nice to do some kind of connection pooling setup in the `ConfigurableWorker.work` method, but I'm unsure of the safety of that without knowing too much about RQ worker fork model with `os.fork()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are taking about python-rq, you may want to read this page [here](http://python-rq.org/docs/) and for config file [here](http://python-rq.org/docs/workers/).

Comment: well, yes python-rq. sure I saw it, but it doesn't seem suitable. I'm not holding values in settings.py, instead I have something like /etc/worker.conf (to give administrator opportunity to change config without committing new values). I parse it with python config parser on worker start. And I want to make those values reachable from the task.

Comment: It would be great if you can show here (with few code snippets) how you parse the settings and how you initiate the worker. That will help folks to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `os` module.

```
#IN WORKER
import os
os.environ['TOKEN'] = 'xxx'

# IN JOB
#Open child processes via os.system(), popen() or fork() and execv()

someVariable = os.environ['TOKEN']
```